# Handling java errors

Tags: java, database

I linked sqlite to java. I want to show a pop up frame to user if there is an error with database but all errors appear in console! how can I manage them?

```
try
    {
        DataBase.databaseConnect("Test");
        DataBase.databaseDataQuery(data);
        DataBase.databaseDisconnect(); 

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane a=new JOptionPane();
        a.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "error");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- catch `SQLException`
- use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(..)` to show a message

Note that you should only tell the end-user that a problem exists. He doesn't care whether that you have a constraint violation, or a missing column.

The whole stacktrace should be logged to a file, or sent directly to you (the vendor)

Comment: Ok I write my code as above. But still I see errors in console!

Comment: Thanks Bozho I could fix that. There was a problem in somewhere else!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(....)` 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html